# Codeigniter query caching causes Blank Screen

Tags: database, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2

I have run into a strange issue.
I had set these parameters in my database.php file as per following:

**$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;**

**$db['default']['cachedir'] = 'cache';**

After this the db cache started working just fine. Then to test, I simply deleted all files in the cache folder and tried to refresh my page but the site went blank.

Even error log is showing nothing. Then I disabled cache by setting it **"False"**, site started to work just fine again.

Can somebody advise me what could be the issue? Whenever I set it to **"True"** again the site goes blank.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `$this->db->CACHE->delete_all()` and trun on the cache also try this deleter after trun on, may be some other file and dir was not deleted

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but even after complete deletion of cache files I am facing the same issue. I even renamed the cache folder and created a new one but all invain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the cache directory path.

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = './my_cache/'
```

So all cache files for the particular page will be stored here.

And I recommended you to enable db_debug as follows so the error will be shown if any in Query

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

For More details, you can refer here : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html

Comment: Thanks @Praburam S, it really worked for me. Sorry for late response :)